# Finding where a variable is stored in Flyway

Tags: maven, variables, amazon-redshift, flyway

I'm running Flyway using Maven, Redshift database and this is what I get:

```
mvn -f postgresql.pom.xml clean compile flyway:migrate -Puat -Denv=xxx -Dxxx.flyway.properties=uat.flyway.properties
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:migrate (default-cli) on project zettabeat: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load Driver class. This error may be caused by all-in-one JAR packaging. Please try again with the lean package.: C:\Users\HP%20(1941).m2\repository\com\amazon\redshift\redshift-jdbc42\1.2.7.1003\redshift-jdbc42-1.2.7.1003.jar (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato - **translated: unable to find the specified path**) -> [Help 1]

It seems like it can't find the path of the Redshift driver in my computer, probably because the directory under user has a blank (it's "HP (1941)").
Where is this variable stored? It's not inside the `pom.xml` or the `uat.flyway.properties` files, not even in the Windows system variables.

I've tried using a few servers that has Maven installed but then he tries to get the necessary driver from an external site and the VPN is blocking this.

Comment: You probably have to add dependency to jdbc driver in Your pom.xml file. See this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html